# Is this syntax as expressive as the do-notation?

Tags: haskell, syntax, do-notation

The `do` notation allows us to express monadic code without overwhelming nestings, so that

```
main = getLine >>= \ a -> 
       getLine >>= \ b ->
       putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

can be expressed as

```
main = do
  a <- getLine
  b <- getLine
  putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

Suppose, though, the syntax allows `... #expression ...` to stand for `do { x <- expression; return (... x ...) }`. For example, `foo = f a #(b 1) c` would be desugared as: `foo = do { x <- b 1; return (f a x c) }`. The code above could, then, be expressed as:

```
main = let a = #getLine in
       let b = #getLine in
       putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

Which would be desugared as:

```
main = do
  x <- getLine
  let a = x in
    return (do
      x' <- getLine
      let b = x' in
        return (putStrLn (a ++ b)))
```

That is equivalent. This syntax is appealing to me because it seems to offer the same functionality as the do-notation, while also allowing some shorter expressions such as:

```
main = putStrLn (#(getLine) ++ #(getLine))
```

So, I wonder if there is anything defective with this proposed syntax, or if it is indeed complete and equivalent to the do-notation.

Comment: Your last example doesn't type check. `(#(getLine) ++ #(getLine)) :: IO String` and is incompatible with `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`.

Comment: Unless `#` has higher precedence than parenthesis!

Comment: @Cirdec how so? It desugars to `do { x <- getLine; return (do { x' <- getLine; return (putStrLn (x ++ x')) }) }`, which typechecks fine.

Comment: @Cirdec it does; I was thinking more like `#` has precedence over everything, basically giving a left-to-right sequential read direction to a block, emulating how procedural languages work.

Comment: How would you sugar nested do notation like [this](https://gist.github.com/Cedev/b55e8bba2d6a33f5023385addbf51c3e)?

Comment: @Cirdec replied there how I think it would look

Comment: Tangential note: the sugar-free version of your last example is `putStrLn =<< (++) <$> getLine <*> getLine`, which makes me think you might find [idiom brackets](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/idiom.html) interesting.

Comment: Or `liftA2 (++) getLine getLine`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`putStrLn` is already `String -> IO ()`, so your desugaring `... return (... return (putStrLn (a ++ b)))` ends up having type `IO (IO (IO ()))`, which is likely not what you wanted: running this program won't print anything!

<s>Speaking more generally, your notation can't express any `do`-block which doesn't end in `return`.</s> [See Derek Elkins' comment.]

I don't believe your notation can express `join`, which can be expressed with `do` without any additional functions:

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
join mx = do { x <- mx; x }
```

However, you can express `fmap` constrained to `Monad`:

```
fmap' :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
fmap' f mx = f #mx
```

and `>>=` (and thus everything else) can be expressed using `fmap'` and `join`. So adding `join` would make your notation complete, but still not convenient in many cases, because you end up needing a *lot* of `join`s.

However, if you drop `return` from the translation, you get something quite similar to [Idris' bang notation](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#monads-and-do-notation):

> In many cases, using do-notation can make programs unnecessarily verbose, particularly in cases such as `m_add` above where the value bound is used once, immediately. In these cases, we can use a shorthand version, as follows:
>
> ```
> m_add : Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
> m_add x y = pure (!x + !y)
> ```
>
> The notation `!expr` means that the expression `expr` should be evaluated and then implicitly bound. Conceptually, we can think of `!` as being a prefix function with the following type:
>
> ```
> (!) : m a -> a
> ```
>
> Note, however, that it is not really a function, merely syntax! In practice, a subexpression `!expr` will lift `expr` as high as possible within its current scope, bind it to a fresh name `x`, and replace `!expr` with `x`. Expressions are lifted depth first, left to right. In practice, !-notation allows us to program in a more direct style, while still giving a notational clue as to which expressions are monadic.
>
> For example, the expression:
>
> ```
> let y = 42 in f !(g !(print y) !x)
> ```
>
> is lifted to:
>
> ```
> let y = 42 in do y' <- print y
>                  x' <- x
>                  g' <- g y' x'
>                  f g'
> ```

Adding it to GHC was discussed, but rejected (so far). Unfortunately, I can't find the threads discussing it.

Comment: Every `do` block that doesn't end in `return` can be trivially rewritten to a `do` block that does end in `return` that is equivalent if the monad laws hold. (Though it may lead to stack overflows as things cease to be tail calls.)

Comment: You are right, this isn't sufficient. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov what happens if we write something like `let y = 42 in f !(g (\k -> !(print y)) !x)` in Idris? Notice the lambda. That is nonsense to me.

Comment: If it isn't clear what `!` does in some case, well, you don't have to use it. (If I understand correctly, since `print y` doesn't depend on `k`, it would be pulled out of the lambda.)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
do a <- something
   b <- somethingElse a
   somethingFinal a b
```